# Extending Java with code that can be used from an Applet

Tags: java, jar, extensibility

I want to extend Java with Classes I made myself so that they can be used from Java Applets. I have tried dropping JAR files in the lib and lib/ext folder but they still ain't globally visible.

Is there something more I have to do for Java to load my classes?

Answer (score 2):

You should not put your classes into lib folder of JRE for a lot of reasons. One of them is that you cannot do it on client machine, i.e. machine of your user that will run your applet via his web browser.

You have to provide correct classpath in your `applet` tag in `html` file.

Comment: They will be packaged and installed on client machines, so that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I do not have to provide correct classpath in my applet for any of the libs in lib and lib/ext that is installed by the java installer. If each JAR in lib must be in the classpath there must be somewhere in the JRE where that classpath is specified.